# How serialize a DRF model class name?

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-rest-framework

I've been given an example JSON output which I must reproduce uisng Django Rest Framework.

Ths is the output:

```
"results": [
    {
      "Brand": [
        {
          "BrandName": "20/20",
          "Store": [
            {
              "ID": "4",
              "User": [
                "1"
              ],
         etc
```

**How do I Model this in DRF?**

Can this be done or have a missed something with models?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should pass **many=True** into Storeserializer

```
class BrandSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    stores = Storeserializer(many=True)
    class Meta:
        """ Serializer configuration. """
        model = Brand
        fields = ("BrandName", "stores")
```

Also, if you get some troubles with field naming, you can use **source** parameter:

```
class SomeModel(...):
    some_field = models.CharField(...)  # pythonic snake_case


class SomeClassSerializer(...):
    class Meta:
        model = SomeModel
        fields = (“SomeField”,)
    SomeField = serializers.CharField(source=“some_field”)  # CamelCase if it needed
```

Comment: Thanks but what about the tip level ie. `"Brand": [` ?

Comment: @MrKnotts If you pass JSON data into BrandSerializer like `serializer = BrandSerializer(data=json_data)` you can also pass into BrandSerializer **many=True**

Comment: Cool. But (many=true)  will not work for Brand only Store in my example. Brand is  `model = Brand`  in my example `BrandSerializer`. where in the json I have to reproduce Brand is an array root level.